# UITableView - Dados da tabela desaparecendo

Tags: ios, swift

Possuo uma `UITableView` simples. Ela é carregada a partir de um `.nib` e adicionada como uma `subview`, ela aparece, carrega os dados, apresenta os mesmos tudo corretamente, porém a partir do momento que eu seleciono uma célula, os dados simplesmente somem.

Atualmente estou utilizando Swift, porém ja tive este mesmo problema com Objective-C, que foi **resolvido sem nenhuma alteração de código**, porém agora não esta mais sendo resolvido.

Segue o código de criação da `UITableView`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        listObjectsToList = ["String 1","String 2","String 3"]

    self.view.frame.size = CGSizeMake(300, 110)
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listObjectsToList.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = listObjectsToList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let objectSelected: AnyObject = listObjectsToList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    object.type = objectSelected as String
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Código de adição como `subview`:

```
var listTypeTableViewController = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TableViewTypeScheduling", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as ListTypeTableViewController
listTypeTableViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 130)
self.view.addSubview(listTypeTableViewController.view)
```

**Vale ressaltar que o método `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` não é chamado**

Comment: Por que você afirma que o método `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` não é chamado? Não será chamado caso você não tenha definido o *delegate* da tabela, foi isso? Porque nesse método você está removendo toda a view (e nela contém a tabela), que seria exatamente o problema.

Comment: Eu coloquei um breakpoint, ele não é chamado e a view não é removida da tela. A classe é uma UITableViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, cheguei ao entendimento do que você pretende fazer, e com isso, você não consegue simplesmente "extrair" a `UITableView` de dentro do seu *controller* para colocar em outra *view*.

Você vai precisar também incluir a `UITableViewController` como "filho" desta que vai recebê-la. Alterei a forma como é adicionado, ficou assim:

```
var listTypeTableViewController = ListTypeTableViewController(nibName: "TableViewTypeScheduling", bundle: nil)        
listTypeTableViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 130)        
addChildViewController(listTypeTableViewController)
view.addSubview(listTypeTableViewController.view)
```

O grande ponto é o método `addChildViewController`, que adicionar o *controller* antes de adicionar a *view* que está dentro dela.

Comment: Obrigado! Nas outras vezes que fiz o mesmo procedimento eu não tinha adicionado ela como "filha", e ainda sim havia dado certo.